# Qual a diferença entre `local function var` e `local var = function...`?

Tags: lua, característica-linguagem

Há duas maneiras de declarar uma função local diretamente.

```
local var = function()
end;
```

e

```
local function var()
end
```

Qual a diferença entre elas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diferença é como a variável local pode ser acessada pelo seu próprio valor (atualmente uma função).

Primeiro é preciso saber que a declaração de uma variável local não é disponível no seu escopo inteiro e pode duplicar, sem problemas. As instruções (statements) seguidas podem referenciar locais declaradas anteriormente, ou campos do ambiente (environment) (global) (`_ENV[nomeDaLocal]` no Lua 5.2).

Enfim, uma funcionalidade simples.

Tipos de casos quando uma função declarada no modelo `local f = function() end` tenta acessar à mesma usando `f`, mas falha:

#1

```
local f = function()
    print(f) -- nil, mas deveria ser a função
end          -- nessa local f.

f()
```

#2

```
local f = 0;

local f = function()
    print(f) -- 0
end

f()
```

#3

```
f = 0;

local f = function()
    print(f) -- 0 também
end

f()
```

A síntaxe especial `local function f() end` cria uma variável local com o nome `f`, e  uma função para ela, uma função que puxa sua presença.

#1

```
local function f()
    print(f) -- ok
end
```

#2

```
local f;

local function f()
    print(f) -- ok
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Citando o [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/pt/manual.html#3.4.10):

O comando

```
 local function f () corpo end
```

é traduzido para

```
 local f; f = function () corpo end
```

não para

```
 local f = function () corpo end
```

(Isso somente faz diferença quando o corpo da função contém referências para `f`.)